# how to retrieve values from dictionary as list in python?

Tags: python-3.x

how to retrieve values from dictionary as list in python?

I can retrieve values by traversing dict but want to know if there is any method.

example:

```
dt = {1:'A', 2:'B'}

result:
['A','B']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can be very easily achieved in python3 by simply doing:

```
list(dt.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
val = list(dt.values())
```

The output is values in dictionary as list: `['A','B']`